# Moving an Image from StackPanel to grid with WPF animation

Tags: wpf, expression-blend-4, wpf-animation

Right now I have several images in a stackpanel as thumbnails and a 3x3 grid for seeing them larger (larger image is in column 1, row 1). I could use a click on a thumbnail in the stackpanel suddenly have a larger version of the image appear in the grid at 1,1, but I would rather have a nice flyout effect starting at the thumbnail and ending in grid column 1 and row 1.

Can someone show me how that would be done, in general?

Comment: Have you looked at the fluidmovebehavior? Been a while since I have but sounds like it might be what you're looking for, if I remember correctly.

Comment: You need to look at the [`Adorner` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx), but your question is off topic for Stack Overflow because a) it is too broad and b) because you have not made your own attempt to fulfil your requirements.

Comment: @kidshaw Thank you for pointing me toward FluidMoveBehavior, just the direction I needed. It did exactly what I needed and it was easy to implement.

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry I didn't have time to write up a proper answer :)